# Vs code not outputting anything

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am using a VS code plugin called [Code Runner Extension (from vscode marketplace)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) and it can't run Javascript and it returns nothing when I run it (only when running JS does this happen). For example, I have a simple js program:

```
console.log("Hello World!")
```

and uh this is the output:
[image: output]

Comment: Did you select the code?

Comment: Also, did you save the file?

Comment: uh one sec imma try that

Comment: Yeah it works but is there a way so I don't have to select the code every time I run it

Comment: If you want to run the whole file, just use a launch configuration in VS Code, or the terminal, or maybe even a watcher like nodemon

Comment: nvm I found out how, you have to tick the "ignore selection" option